# Angular 4 : Tile implementation

Tags: angular, typescript, angular4-forms

I am very new to angular 4 and new to a project as well. My lead has asked me to do an analysis whether the below design is achievable in angular 4 or not.

I can easily achieve the design using CSS but I am not sure how is this related or achievable in angular 4.

Please guide me whether this design is achievable or not.

I came across `<mat-grid-list>` in angular 4, can I use this?

**Scenario**: Onclick of "tile1" (1st picture)... "tile1a","tile1b","tile1c" should appear (2nd picture)

[image]

[image]

Comment: It is achievable, split all sections in components and call them appropriately

Answer (score 0):

I can only agree with the comment of @mxr7350. Create a template using html/css and split nav-bar, side-bar and the tiles into components to achive your goals. If you're new to angular I'd suggest that you complete the [Tour of Heroes](https://angular.io/tutorial) and if you require further help you could create a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-djzven) so others can help you with your layouts and components. A full example of the code required can hardly be posted in an comment here, but yea it's achtivable.

Best regards

Comment: Yes, this will help. Thanks